# django orm depth search

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

guys i have three classes

```
class A(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
image1 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 1 Image",upload_to='product')
image2 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 2 Image",upload_to='product')
image3 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 3 Image",upload_to='product')
color = models.ForeignKey(color)
stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def admin_thumbnail(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" heigh="150" width="200" />' % (self.image1.url)
admin_thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
admin_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s ' % (self.id)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "MTI Image"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

class B(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
a = models.ForeignKey(A)
size = models.ForeignKey(size)
weight = models.FloatField()
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s - %s %s' % (self.barcode,self.mtiimage.image1,self.size.name)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "MTD"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

class C(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
item = models.ForeignKey(item)
b= models.ManyToManyField(B)
country = models.ForeignKey(country)
dept = models.ForeignKey(dept)
fabric = models.ForeignKey(fabric)
sesason = models.ForeignKey(season)
sale = models.FloatField()
endUser = models.FloatField()
description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
year = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=strftime("%Y", gmtime()))
front_page = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Front Page",default=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s - %s' % (self.name, self.description)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "MTI"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

what i want

```
myC = c.objects.get(pk=1)
```

in template
will use three loops to display data

```
for tmpc in myC:
    for tmpb in tmpc.B:
        for tmpa in tmpb.A
            print tmpa.image1
```

i tried many time but i failed

```
myC = C.objects.get(pk=1)
myC.B
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for tmpc in myC:
    for tmpb in tmpc.B.all():
        for tmpa in tmpb.A.all():
            print tmpa.image1
```

And give your classes a decent name while you're at it ;)

Comment: just .all, without the parenthesis.
please accept a answer if it works for you...